# String Size/Query in Mapbasic

Tags: mapbasic

I want to select many objects on the screen and select other objects that share the same attributes with the chosen group.

So I'm creating a tool to select many object based in five tables' columns attributes.
The tools works fine but when I select 3 or more objects the query became much bigger and I lost part of them.

Is there a way to do a query using to variables?
Something like: "Run command varA + varB"
Or is there a way to increase the string's size?

Comment: Can you share the string that you create? There is a limit to how long a SQL string can be - I think it's around 512 characters. Maybe your string can can structured in a different way to reach the same result